# How can I read httponly and secure cookies in the browser with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, httpcookie

How can I read httponly and secure cookies in the browser with Javascript, With "document.cookie" I can only see non httponly ones. I also need to access cookies that are httponly and secure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't. HttpOnly cookies are sent over https and stored in the browser and not accessible by javascript.