# How can I read the value of a HttpOnly cookie?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies, session-cookies, httpcookie

I'm using python and selenium to browse a website, once logged in I would like to transfer the session (exporting cookies) from the selenium browser to a python requests session, but I noticed that there is a cookie called "session-token " which is not transferred, I also noticed that this cookie is marked as:

- HostOnly
- Secure
- HttpOnly

I've already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064318/how-to-read-a-httponly-cookie-using-javascript), using [Postman's Interceptor bridge](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/syncing-cookies/) extension and synchronizing cookies, I noticed that the "session-token" cookie is exported to the desktop program, how is this possible? Is there any way to read the value of this cookie?

I tried logging in directly using requests but the cookie is not being set.
I also tried to print the cookies using the console, this is the code:

```
var theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0 ; i <= theCookies.length; i++) {
   console.log(theCookies[0] );
}
```

but the cookie is not printed.

Answer (score 1):

The "session-token" cookie you mentioned is likely being set as a secure and HttpOnly cookie.

see this link:
[How can I read httponly and secure cookies in the browser with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72889905/how-can-i-read-httponly-and-secure-cookies-in-the-browser-with-javascript).

if you want you can extract cookies manually:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# Do necessary actions to log in and navigate to the desired page
# ...

# Get cookies from Selenium
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `selenium` there's a method to get all of the cookies

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# this will return all the cookies context
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

if you tend to using Python's requests, you can achieve that with called this method

```py
session = requests.Session()
resp = session.get("your-target-url")

# this will return as dictionary object
print(resp.cookies.get_dict())
```